# How can I implement a control structure to bypass some layers in keras?

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

I want to implement a structure like this in Keras:
[figure1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRfOo.png)

the purpose of this structure is to selective bypass some layers in a model, the gate signal should be learnable (binary 0 or 1).

Answer (score 0):

Use a mask: calculate the mask from the input, and then multiply the output of layer 2 by the mask.